# getting error Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object String]`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react, react-final-form

I am getting this error while using `multiselect` with `final-form`.

> Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received
>   type: `[object String]`

here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-torvalds-lhe9d

```
<Dropdown
        {...props.input}
        clearable
        fluid
        multiple
        search
        onChange={(e, data) => {
          return data.value.length > 0
            ? input.onChange(data.value)
            : input.onChange("");
        }}
        onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
        selection
        defaultValue={[]}
        options={data}
        placeholder="Select values"
      />
```

any update?

Comment: Code in sandbox works well..

Comment: see console..and check error

Comment: Error went away when `defaultValue={[]}` is replaced with `value={[]}` in `example.js` file. See if that works for you..

Comment: then user not able to select value ..:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove defaultValue prop and pass value prop as [] if value is not available to Dropdown component.

```
const SingleSelectAutoComplete = props => {
  const renderError = ({ error, touched }, id) => {
    if (touched && error) {
      return <div id={id}>{error}</div>;
    }
  };
  const {
    input,
    label,
    onSearchChange,
    data,
    meta,
    required,
    onChange,
    helloWorld
  } = props;
  console.log("***********************");
  let { value, ...restProps } = props.input;
  const id = input.name;
  return (
    <div
      className={`field ${meta.error && meta.touched ? " error" : ""} ${
        required ? " required" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <label>{label}</label>
      <Dropdown
        {...restProps}
        value={value || []}
        clearable
        fluid
        multiple
        search
        onChange={(e, data) => {
          return data.value.length > 0
            ? input.onChange(data.value)
            : input.onChange("");
        }}
        onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
        selection
        options={data}
        placeholder="Select values"
      />
      {renderError(meta, `${id}-error-text`)}
    </div>
  );
};
```